# 2 validation groups

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have 2 validation forms on page.

```
<div id='LogOn' style="background-color: White;">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogOnAjax", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "LogOn", OnSuccess = "logInComplete" }))
    { 
        //ITW2012Mobile.ViewModels.LogOnModel m = Model;
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsLoggedIn)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReturnUrl)
        <div>
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

and

```
<fieldset>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(Model.ActionMethod, Model.Controller))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
.....
            <div class="display-label"> E-mail Address * </div>
            <div class="display-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
            </div>
            <div class="display-label"> Create Password * </div>
            <div class="display-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    }
</fieldset>
```

How can I mark that `ModelState.AddModelError` is for first of form, because I see the same error in the both places of `validation summary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I mark that ModelState.AddModelError is for first of form

You can't.

What you can do is having `ValidationMessageFor` for each form properties instead of the `ValidationSummary`

Comment: but I need validation summary in both places. Is exist solution?

Comment: @John. You can make your own custom `validation summary` `HtmlHelper` with the logic you want.